# Can I use facebook sdk for Android without install facebook.apk?

Tags: java, android, facebook, sdk

Do I have to install facebook.apk on my android device before try to use facebook sdk for android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short and simple: No, you don't.

Answer (score 2):

It will use the browser/web view for authentication and whatnot if the facebook app isn't installed. Which is great for development, however, you should probably test with both scenarios before you publish.